# Sum of different items in a pandas df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have this [data](https://github.com/Ewallk/Fixacao/blob/main/total%20cargo.xlsx?raw=true) and I need to sum the total ['Tons'] per ['KeyCode´] and how to show all the ['Origin'] that make this total.

I did a groupby by KeyCode, but I can't figure out how to proceed.

```
df = data.groupby("KeyCode", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x)
df.head()
```

Comment: please don't provide data as a link, paste a sample of it as text into your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use all aggregation functions in a groupby object to get the values you are interested on.

To get the total of something, the function is `sum()`, whereas to get the unique values we use `unique()`. To use `unique` you must first get the series (a column, in Excel language) related to the variable you want to get the unique values for each value of the groupby variable.

See the code and result below:

```
data = pd.read_excel("total cargo.xlsx")

# get total of 'Tons'
res = data.groupby("KeyCode", group_keys=False).sum()

# get all the 'Origin' values for each keycode
res['Origins'] = data.groupby("KeyCode", group_keys=False)['Origin'].unique()

res.head()
```

[image: res.head]